# Securely Handling Azure AD Access Tokens with NextAuth.js in a Next.js Application

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication, security, token

I am working on a Next.js application where I'm using NextAuth.js for authentication with Azure AD. After successful authentication, I am obtaining the access token, which I later use for calls to the Microsoft Graph API.

However, I've noticed that the access token is visible in the React context when viewed with React Dev Tools. Here's a simplified example of how I'm handling authentication:

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID!,
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'openid profile user.Read email' },
    url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID!}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
    },
    token: { params
      : { scope: 'openid profile user.Read email' },
    url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID!}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
    },
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      console.log("JWT token", token);

      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
      console.log("Session token", token);
      if (token) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      }
      return session
    }
    
  },

  
  
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

And then, in my components, I'm accessing this token like this:

```
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function Component() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log("accesstoken", session.accessToken);

  // I then use session.accessToken to make authenticated calls to the Microsoft Graph API.
}
```

While I understand that the token is short-lived and specific to a user and session, I am still concerned about its visibility in the React context, as it contains sensitive information.

Is this approach secure or are there better ways to handle the access token on the client side in a Next.js application using NextAuth.js?
Should I be concerned about the visibility of the access token in the React context?
If this is a security risk, what alternative strategies can I use to store and manage the access token securely?
Thank you in advance for your guidance.

I already thought about throwing the user data to a database using next-auth adapter, and when I need the accessToken, get it from the db, but that doesn't seem like a very good option either, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a very valid concern about exposing the JWT on the client-side when you add it to the `session`. When you do this, you are negating the work that NextAuth does to encrypt the details you've added to the JWT before storing it client-side.

Maybe you can remove the access token from your session and rely on your server to handle authenticated requests to MS Graph? Might also be good to explore using the adapter again as NextAuth will store any custom session data in the DB without doing any extra work.

I don't know which version of Next you are using, so I'll just assume it's Next@13 for this example.

First update your NextAuth config to remove the access token from the session. Also add an adapter of your choosing.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import AzureADProvider from 'next-auth/providers/azure-ad';
// Use whichever adapter suits you. This is just an example.
import { DynamoDBAdapter } from '@auth/dynamodb-adapter'

const client = /* your db client */

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      /* your config here */
    }),
  ],
  // Use whichever adapter suits you. This is just an example.
  adapter: DynamoDBAdapter(
    client
  ),
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      console.log("JWT token", token);

      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (token) {
        // Instead of returning the access token, maybe you could only return
        // the properties you want to see on the FE that aren't
        // considered sensitive data. e.g.
        session.user.roles = token.roles;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Next let's create an API route that will query MS Graph

```
// app/api/msgraph/route.ts

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const token = await getToken({ req })

  // If the user isn't signed in, redirect
  if (!token) return redirect('/signin')

  // Modify the fetch request to match your needs
  const res = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{resource}?{query-parameters}', {
    // Add the  access token to your request
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token?.accessToken}` },
  })

  const data = await res.json()
 
  return NextResponse.json({ data })
}
```

Then you can just call this API endpoint like so:

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

export default function Component() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('/api/msgraph', fetcher)
  
  if (error) return <div>❌</div>
  if (isLoading) return <div>‍</div>
  
  console.log('ms graph response', data)
  return <div>{data.someProp}</div>
}
```

Code may be buggy as I am just writing this on the fly, but I think it will suit your needs and alleviate your concerns about sharing the access token in your application.

Related to your posted code, you may want to think about grabbing the below details in a more secure manner:

```
clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID!,
clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET!,
tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID!
```

This will present a security concern if you are storing them as environment variables for your Lambda, Azure Function, or EC2 instance, etc...

Hope this answer helps!